# Using advanced filter with criteria

Tags: vba, excel, filtering

I am trying to copy distinct values from excel table with VBA, but I am running in trouble when I want to assing criteria to it.

I am trying to filter the values which are bigger than zero in column `CI`

This code does work

```
Dim KeyCells As Range
Set KeyCells = Range("H1")        
    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then    
Dim lastrow As Long    
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Range("H1").Value
Application.EnableEvents = False
    Sheets("Fond16").Range("C4:C31").Clear
    Sheets("PlneniOperatoru_2016").Range("B" & lastrow - 1 & "11:B" & lastrow & "11").AdvancedFilter _
    Action:=xlFilterCopy,  _
    CopyToRange:=Sheets("Fond16").Range("C4"), _
    Unique:=True
```

But this does not work (Will throw 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error)

```
Sheets("PlneniOperatoru_2016").Range("B" & lastrow - 1 & "11:B" & lastrow & "11").AdvancedFilter _
Action:=xlFilterCopy, Criteria:="CI>0", _
CopyToRange:=Sheets("Fond16").Range("C4"), _
Unique:=True
```

I would love to know If I can somehow rephrase the Criteria parameter to make it working. Thanks in advance :)

EDIT:I am currently trying to use this code, In the criteria range is

```
CI
>0
```

And it does only show the first value, but sometimes the first value is with 0 in CI column so the criteria clearly does not work

```
Sheets("PlneniOperatoru_2016").Range("B" & lastrow - 1 & "11:B" & lastrow & "11").AdvancedFilter _
    Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=Sheets("2016").Range("X1:X2"), _
    CopyToRange:=Sheets("Fond16").Range("C4:C31"), _
    Unique:=False
```

Comment: Did you try: ... `, Field:=87, Criteria:=">0",` ... ? (Field 87 for column CI)

Comment: `AdvancedFilter` has no option `Criteria`, only `CriteriaRange` ([see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841242.aspx))

Comment: Still the same error :( @Rémi

Comment: Can you please explain how the `CriteriaRange` works ? I could not find any documentation of it @arcadeprecinct

Comment: @arcadeprecinct: you are right, sorry for that.

Comment: @Hynek Bernard: maybe you could do an autofilter using the field and criteria and copy the visible cells instead ?

Comment: @HynekBernard I wish I could^^. There are some examples out there. I think you need headers on your data (so a header for column CI and then the criteria `CIheader` and `>0` in a range? I have no idea, I've never even used regular filters ;)

Comment: @HynekBernard The `Advanced Filter` does not have a `Criteria` paramater. Look at Excel Help for the `Advanced Filter`, and you will find numerous examples of how to set up and use the `Criteria Range`.  You can then add that range to your worksheet, and reference it in your VBA macro.